# How to get webpack multiple-entry-points example working with webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've been struggling to get this example project working with webpack-dev-server.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-entry-points

So what I'm expecting to happen is that after I serve it up, I can go to `localhost:8080/pageA` and `localhost:8080/pageB` to see my different entry points.

I've set up my `package.json` like so:

```
{
  "name": "multiple-entry-points",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This example shows how to use multiple entry points with a commons chunk.",
  "main": "build.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to run it like so:

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base ./public
```

(If I don't put in the --inline, etc, I just get a directory listing).

No luck. `localhost:8080/pageA` doesn't work, etc. I'm not even sure that my expectations are correct here.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no url `localhost:8080/pageA` and `localhost:8080/pageB`

There is `js` bundle `pageA.js` and `pageB.js`

You may want to open url `localhost:8080/pageA.html` and `localhost:8080/pageAB.html`

Entry point is `js` bundle. You need to include it in html page like this:

```html
<script src="js/pageA.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: I tried visiting http://localhost:8080/pageA.html, but I just get

Cannot GET /pageA.html.

Is this example broken?